# Another empty row with time stamp added with every entry in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

another empty row with timestamp added in mysql database each time a new row with entries added ,
here is part of my code

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "zaheer442";
$dbname = "76H";

// Create connection
 $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} else {
echo "wooo connected";
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO 76Hlog (Device_ID, Response_status, Device_NO, Status, Time) VALUES ('$keywords[4]', '$keywords[8]', '$keywords[15]', '$keywords[17]', now())";
if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql)){
echo "Records inserted successfully.";
} else{
echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}


//displaying data
$sql = "SELECT Device_ID, Response_status, Device_NO, Status FROM 76H";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "id: " . $row["Device_ID"]. " - Staus: " . $row["Response_status"]. " Devic No " .  $row["Device_NO"]. " Mode " .  $row["Status"]. "<br>";
}
} else {
echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();
```

**[Entries Screenshot has also attached]**

[image]

Comment: How are you using this code? Looks like the query executes twice, perhaps you'll need to add some checking to verify that your form is sent (assuming it is through a form)

Comment: rename $sql for select query try.

Comment: is there a trigger? or a second (hidden) submit?

Comment: Doesn't matter, @prasanna, the variable is overwritten before the query is executed, and a select would not insert new rows.

Comment: Please check code :- <?php 
if(!empty($keywords)){
   $sql = "INSERT INTO 76Hlog (Device_ID, Response_status, Device_NO, Status, Time) VALUES ('$keywords[4]', '$keywords[8]', '$keywords[15]', '$keywords[17]', now())";
   if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql)){
    echo "Records inserted successfully.";
   } else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
   }
 }
 ?>

Comment: @sunnybhadania didn't  work , i think problem is with mysql, it is start showing empty rows when i inserted timedate column

Comment: And now change your password

Comment: @Strawberry doesn't matter it's on localhost

Comment: It matters if you use that password in other contexts. And anyway, things change.